# git push php and host key verification failed

Tags: php, git, ssh

```
$commitMessage = 'Auto commit from admin panel '.date('d.m.Y H:i:s', time());

chdir(__DIR__.'/../../../..');
$res[] = shell_exec('git add --all 2>&1');
$res[] = shell_exec('git commit -a -m "'.$commitMessage.'" 2>&1');
$res[] = shell_exec('git push origin master 2>&1');
$res[] = shell_exec('git status 2>&1');
```

Output after git push command:
**Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.**

But before i run follow commands:

```
sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R ~/.ssh/known_hosts
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /project
```

(where locate .git directory)

After I add ssh key to bitbucket ssh keys (not for deploying).

Comment: Have you tried to manually clone as being www-data? (`su www-data` as root to get a shell)

Comment: This is access denied...
http://www.howtogeek.com/168119/fixing-warning-unprotected-private-key-file-on-linux/

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the host key for the domain you're connecting to (bitbucket, I assume, from your comment) has changed. It's their key that's different, not yours.

I'd check to see if they've changed their host key recently, and, if they have, you can remove the old key with

```
$ ssh-keygen -R bitbucket.org
```

Be careful though, an unknown host key *could* mean a man-in-the-middle attack. So be sure it's really bitbucket's key before doing this.

Comment: Okey, i run this command from php env. But this error not resolved after it.
And I check known_hosts and this command return:
/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts updated. Original contents retained as /var/www/.ssh/known_hosts.old

Comment: @DanielAndreyev, hmm, okay, try running `git remote -v` to verify that it's actually bitbucket that's your remote. If it's not, again, verify that the host key has changed and then remove it if necessary.

Comment: But git remote -v returned me correct answer - two repository for pull and push...
If i run git push origin master at the terminal it's worked, but if i use shell_exec it's not worked.

Comment: I resolve this problem!
http://www.howtogeek.com/168119/fixing-warning-unprotected-private-key-file-on-linux/